# how to migrate the source code(downgrade) of ios from mac 10.7 to mac 10.6.8

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am new to ios developement.
I have two mac books. one mac os  is `10.6.8 with xcode version 4.2`  and another `mac os is 10.7 with xcode version 4.3.3`.

The source code is in 10.7 mac version. it is running and working fine . I want to migrate the source code which is in 10.7 to 10.6 mac version.

I have copy the source code from working machine (i.e 10.7) and open that source code in xcode 4.3.3(i.e in mac osx 10.6.8)

Lots of errors are coming like sematic issues instace method not found return type defaults to id

for pseduo code, `[self addApplicationObservers];` ..instance method -`addApplicationObservers` not found(return type defaulst to id)

Implementation is provided for `addApplicationObservers`. But declaration is missing in h or m file. But it works in mac osx 10.7 with xcode 4.3.3

If i provide the declarations for each one, its very tough job.Because i have so many classes.

What is the reason for those errors?

Is there any perquisites to downgrade the source code from mac `osx 10.7 to 10.6.8` and please tell the required sdk's

Please provide me a solutions to run the code without errors

thank you
Chaitanya

Comment: Do you need to support _compilation_ under 10.6.8, or just running under 10.6.8?  If you only need to run under 10.6.8, I'd suggest setting the minimum deployment target in your 10.7 Xcode build and testing for compatibility.  As you have already noticed, moving source code back to 10.6.8 will be a detailed and aggravating task, as you not only have to deal with changes in the APIs, but also with differences in the compilers, which are pretty significant at that point.  As for the reason it is difficult, you are working with 2 different deployment and development environments.

Comment: The mac osx 10.7 is not working now .I have backup of source code. Now i  have mac osx 10.6.8 with me. So i want to run the source code  in mac osx 10.6.8 with xcode 4.2 & ios sdk 5.0(showing base sdk 5.0 only). Is there any other option to run properly ?

Answer (score 0):

If your program is building for iOS, the only things that matter are what compiler you're using and which iOS SDK you're using. It sounds as though your 10.6.8 machine has an older SDK installed in its version of iOS.

Can you verify that both machines have the same iOS SDKs installed?

Comment: Both macs having different ios sdk versions. 10.7 mac is sdk 5.1 whereas 10.6.8 is having  sdk5.0. sdk 5.1 is not available there to update

Comment: Is there any reason not to get the latest SDK on the 10.6.8 machine? I'd always build against the latest.

Comment: in my mac it is not showing sdk 5.1 update. i dont know the reason.

Comment: Well, none—the iOS SDKs come with Xcode, not with a particular OS.